# appending 2 lists at the same time

Tags: python, list

I have a function that draws rectangles:

```
def drawTbl(l, w):

    ln1 = ' '
    ln2 = '-'
    ln3 = '|'

    x = range(l)
    print '+', ln2*w, '+'
    for i in range(len(x)):
        print ln3, ln1*w, ln3
    print '+', ln2*w, '+'
```

It works fine, but I'm attempting to kind of graph this (this is like a pong clone) so that I can place a ball 'O' at the center and use X and Y for collision detection.  When I use this function:

```
def tblData(l, w):
    table=[]
    for x in range(l):
        table.append([])
    for y in range(w):
        table.append([])
```

It does seem to append the blank lists, but when I try to use `table[x][y]`, all I receive is an error.

When I return `table` from `tblData`, I do get a list of empty lists,
but say `(l, w)` is `(12, 56)`, so I'm trying to place ball 'O' at the center of the grid `(6, 28)`, simply typing `table[6][28]` returns an error, so I don't know how I would append 'O' to `table[6,28]`

So my question is, how can I effectively access `list[x][y]`?

Comment: F.J's answer is good, but you also have the problem that you're not making a two-dimensional array. You're making a list with l + w empty lists inside of it.

Comment: you're right, this works well when calling pprint, but I still haven't manipulated this to place objects (while still using my original rectangle function)  I'll do some reading on 2d arrays, if you've got any advice that'd be cool, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of creating empty lists you will need to initialize the values in the inner lists to some reasonable value, like a space.

For example:

```
def tblData(l, w):
    table=[]
    for x in range(l):
        table.append([' '] * w)
    return table
```

Or more concisely:

```
def tblData(l, w):
    return [[' '] * w for x in range(l)]
```

Note that `[' '] * 3` creates the list `[' ', ' ', ' ']`, so `[' '] * w` is equivalent to
 `[' ' for x in range(w)]`.

For example:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> table = [[' '] * 4 for x in range(5)]
>>> pprint.pprint(table)
[[' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]
>>> table[3][1] = 'O'
>>> pprint.pprint(table)
[[' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', 'O', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]
```